# Copying a String From a Vector to a String

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string s;
    string s1;
    vector<string> images;
    cout<<"enter the names";
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        cin>>s;
        images.push_back(s);
    }
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<images.size();i++)
    {
        cout<<images.at(i)<<endl;
        strcpy(s1,images.at(i));
        cout<<s1;
    }
}
```

How do I copy a string from the vector into another string?

Comment: Why do you copy the string?

Comment: i am following the tutorial on http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_video_recognition.html

Comment: now i want to change the label from as name of the user     prediction =6  as     prediction=john  how to do that

Answer (score 2):

Just use assignment:

```
s1 = images.at(i);
```

Note that in your code sample there is no reason to make that copy.